# create pygame.Color sometimes throws ValueError: invalid color argument

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I am trying to modify the color value of a pixel by constructing a `pygame.Color` object from a integer tuple, but for some reason I cannot do what is normally quite possible:

```
import pygame
import numpy
import random

# it is possible to create a pygame.Color from a tuple of values:
random_values = tuple((random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(4)))
color = pygame.Color(*random_values)
print(f"successfully created pygame.Color: {color}")

# now for some real application. A certain pixel has this color:
pixel_color = pygame.Color(2795939583) # (166, 166, 166, 0)
print(f"pixel color: {pixel_color}")

# planning to change the intensity of the individual color channels R, G, B, A:
intensity = 25
factors = (1, -1, 1, 0)

# the following will add or subtract 25 from each channel in the pixel_color (while keeping them in range [0,255]):
# pixel_color:     (166, 166, 166, 0)
# relative change: (+25, -25, +25, 0)
# resulting color: (191, 141, 191, 0)
numpy_values = tuple(numpy.clip(channel + (intensity * factor), 0, 255) for channel, factor in zip(pixel_color, factors))
print(f"numpy values: {numpy_values}")
new_pixel_color = pygame.Color(*numpy_values)
```

While the first instance of `pygame.Color` can be created from the `random_values` tuple, I cannot create another `pygame.Color` instance from the `numpy_values` tuple. Yet both tuples seem identical in `type` and `repr`. I get this output:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
successfully created pygame.Color: (143, 12, 128, 61)
pixel color: (166, 166, 166, 255)
numpy values: (191, 141, 191, 255)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal.py", line 24, in <module>
    new_pixel_color = pygame.Color(*numpy_values)
ValueError: invalid color argument
```

Comment: you can use `max(min(255, value), 0)` intead of `numpy.clip(value, 0, 255)` and it will give integers.

Comment: good suggestion, that way the module would not have the numpy dependency. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the `numpy.clip` was not a real integer! the `numpy_values` was not a tuple of integers.

After converting the results to int, the problem is solved!

```
numpy_values = tuple(int(numpy.clip(channel + (intensity * factor), 0, 255)) for channel, factor in zip(pixel_color, factors))
```